# NSInteger set to 0 but returns nil

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an NSInteger in my class like so

In @interface:

```
NSInteger currentRow;    

@property (assign) NSInteger currentRow;
```

In @implementation:

```
@synthesize currentRow;
```

Doing `[self setCurrentRow:0]` seems to work fine, but using `[self currentRow]` just returns null for some reason, not sure why. When using breakpoints I can see that the value for `currentRow` is `0` so it has set fine, but I can't get the value back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Objective-C, it's important that you distinguish between objects and primitive types.

An **object** is always stored as a pointer, which is the object's location in memory. A pointer is just a number. With `NSLog`, you can use `%p` to see this value. You can display it in the debugger too, like this: `print myObject`. A pointer is displayed as a hexadecimal number, with a `0x` prefix. `nil` is essentially location zero (`0x0000`). When you allocate any kind of object, you'll get a pointer which isn't zero. When you assign an object to a variable, you are simply copying the memory address, not duplicating the object. With `NSLog`, you can use `%@` to print out an object's `description`. In the debugger, like this: `print-object myObject`.

**Primitive types** like `NSInteger` aren't objects. Instead of storing a pointer, usually you just store the value. When you assign an `NSInteger` variable, you make a copy of the value. You can see the value in the debugger using `print`. Or like this: `NSLog("%ld", (long)currentRow)`. When you assign a primitive, you copy its value. Don't use `%@` or `print-object` with primitives — they expect objects.

(I say "usually you just store the value," because you can make pointers to primitive types, too. In situations like yours however it's not necessary.)

`[self currentRow]` returns 0, just like you set it. (Furthermore, because Objective-C guarantees initialization of instance variables, it'll return 0 even if you *don't* set it.)

The problem is that you're expecting a pointer to an object. How you fix your code depends on how you're using it:

- If you're using `print-object currentRow`, change it to `print currentRow`.
- If you're using `NSLog("%@", currentRow)`, change it to `NSLog(%"ld", (long)currentRow)`.
- If you're using `currentRow` somewhere else, where an object is required, change your instance variable and property types to `NSNumber *`, an object type. Set it with `[self setCurrentRow:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]`.

Answer (score 6):

NSInteger is not object, it's typedef'd to int or something like that. Thus, if you set currentRow to 0 and then try to get it back, null (aka 0) is totally correct value.

Comment: It's a assign not a retain property so it should work with non-object types

Comment: And it works! In terms of actual value in memory, null and 0 are the same thing. Try `[self setCurrentRow:42]`, you'll see then that `[self currentRow]` returns 42, just make sure you are assigning result to NSInteger, not to an object.

Comment: Yes it's totaly valid to use properties that are non-objects as long as you define them as `assign` so that sythesize will skip the retain/release dance

Answer (score 4):

The getter method will be synthesized as `- (NSInteger)currentRow` so it should work just fine. But how do you check if it works? With `NSLog(@"%@", ...)`? Than you should use `%d`.

If you want it to be an object you should use `NSNumber` and a `retain` property.