# selectedRow return null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

i have a NSTableView on a window, the data is populated using a NSMutableArray and that is Ok

after selecting a rows, when i check in code

```
[myTableView selectedRow];
```

or

```
[myTableView clickedRow];
```

both return null

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"Table view: %@", myTableView);` say?

Comment: it shows null,  what is the way out?

Comment: What's the declaration of `myTableView`?  It sounds as if it's not an outlet to your actual table view object (since you say your display is OK).

Comment: Are you sure it is `NULL` and not `nil`? If it is `NULL` your outlet is initialized.

Comment: How do you mean `id is null`? What id?

Comment: A nil value is formatter an (null). Anyway selectedRow and clickedRow don't return a pointer, so if they return NULL it means that the selected/clicked row is the first, or that the table view is nil (that is your case).

Comment: got its up and running, Thanks.  I now have the issue regarding updating controls in a 2nd window, which i posted separately.

Comment: Jaggu, answer you own question then, to assist others coming here with the same problem.

Comment: `nil` and `NULL` are the same pointer, just in different types. The two values are equal and indistinguishable; `nil` == `NULL`. Thus, it is impossible for an outlet, or any other property or ivar that holds an object pointer, to be `NULL` and yet not `nil`. Moreover, an outlet that has been “initialized” (by which I assume @11684 means “is connected in a nib that has been loaded”) will not be `nil` and consequently will not be `NULL` either.

Comment: @Jaggu: You should post an answer (even though this is your own question—this is actively encouraged) explaining what the problem was and how you solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectedRow` and `clickedRow` each return an `NSInteger`, not an object. They're returning 0, which is the index of the first row.

If you print `0` as if it were an object (e.g., with `NSLog(@"%@", [myTableView selectedRow])`), it will print as `nil`, simply because that's what `nil` is: `0` as an object pointer.

---

Of course, this assumes that `myTableView` actually refers to a table view in the first place. If `myTableView` does not yet point to a table view (i.e., the `myTableView` variable itself holds `nil`), any message to it will in turn return `0` (which, again, looks like `nil` if you treat it as an object).

If `selectedRow` returns `0` when the first row isn't selected or there are no rows, or `clickedRow` returns `0` when the first row hasn't been clicked, make sure `myTableView` points where you expect it to.

(I'm deliberately leaving the more specific explanation of the problem and its solution to you, Jaggu, since you said in the comments that you found it already.)

Comment: Here's an explanation I gave of the difference between objects and primitive types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707008/nsinteger-set-to-0-but-returns-nil/7719285#7719285